# Why do we build "inside" docker?

Tags: docker

When I first learned Docker I expected a config file, image producer, CLI, and options for mounting and networks. That's all there.

I did not expect to put build commands inside a Dockerfile. I thought docker would wrap/tar/include a prebuilt task I made. Why give build commands in Docker?

Surely it can import a task thus keeping Jenkins/Bazel etc. distinct and apart for making an image/container?

Comment: "give build commands in docker" --- because the host machine **does not** have all the necessary building infrastructure.

Answer (score 6):

I guess we are dealing with a misconception here. Docker is NOT a lighweight version of VMware/Xen/KVM/Parallels/FancyVirtualization.

> **Disclaimer: The following is *heavily* simplified for the sake of comprehensiveness.**

### So what *is* Docker?

In one sentence: Docker is a system to isolate processes from the other processes *within* an operating system as much as possible while still providing all means to run them. Put differently:

> Docker is a package manager for isolated processes.

One of its closest ancestors are chroot and BSD jails. What those basically do is to isolate (more in the case of BSD, less in the case of chroot) a part of your OS resources and have a complete environment running independently from the rest of the OS - *except* for the kernel.

In order to be able to do that, a Docker image obviously needs to contain everything *except* for a kernel. So you need to provide a shell (if you choose to do so), standard libraries like glibc and even resources like CA certificates. For reference: In order to set up chroot jails, you did all this by hand once upon a time, preinstalling your chroot environment with each and every piece of software required. Docker is basically taking the heavy lifting from you here.

The mentioned isolation even down to the installed (and usable software) sounds cumbersome, but it gives you several advantages as a developer. Since you provide basically everything except for a (compatible) kernel, you can develop and test your code in the same environment it will run later down the road. Not a close approximation, but literally the same environment, bit for bit. A rather famous proverb in relation to Docker is:

> *"Runs on my machine" is no excuse any more.*

Another advantage is that can add static resources to your Docker image and access them via quite ordinary file system semantics. While it is true that you can do that with virtualisation images as well, they usually do not come with a language for provisioning. Docker does - the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine
LABEL maintainer="you@example.com"
COPY file/in/host destination/on/image
```

### Ok, got it, now why the build commands?

As described above, you need to provide *all* dependencies (and transitive dependencies) your application has. The easiest way to ensure that is to build your application inside your Docker image:

```
FROM somebase
RUN yourpackagemanager install long list of dependencies && \
make yourapplication && \
make install
```

If the build fails, you know you have missing dependencies. Now you can tweak and tune your `Dockerfile` until it compiles and is tested. So now your Docker image is finished, you can confidently distribute it, since you *know* that as long as the docker daemon runs on the machine somebody tries to run your image on, your image will run.

In the Go ecosystem, you basically assure your `go.mod` and `go.sum` are up to date and working and your work stay's reproducible.

### Again, this works with virtualisation as well, so where is the deal?

A (good) docker image only runs what it needs to run. In the vast majority of docker images, this means exactly one process, for example your Go program.

> Side note: It is **very** bad practise to run multiple processes in one Docker image, say your application and a database server and a cache and whatnot. That is what [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) is there for, or more generally container orchestration. But this is far too big of a topic to explain here.

A virtualised OS, however, needs to run a kernel, a shell, drivers, log systems and whatnot.

So the deal basically is that you get all the good stuff (isolation, reproducibility, ease of distribution) with less waste of resources (running 5 versions of the same OS with all its shenanigans).

Comment: Nice explanation. Thank you. Now, just for the record is it possible to make a valid image (hence container) without embedding build commands. This question derives from the principle objective of deploying complete, valid tasks. Indeed the task, libs and other dependencies may exist prebuilt. I'm guessing no.

Comment: @ecwdw23e3e23e Sure. Simply run `docker run [docker-flags] chosen/image [commandDifferingFromStandard] [commandOrEntrypointparams]`, say [`docker run -p 27017 mongo`](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) or `docker run --name some-mongo -d mongo --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB 1.5`.

Comment: Thank you. However, this was more what I was looking for: https://medium.com/@chemidy/create-the-smallest-and-secured-golang-docker-image-based-on-scratch-4752223b7324

Comment: @ecwdw23e3e23e You do not *have* to use build commands. Actually, something as [simple as this](https://pastebin.com/X7TTw8UZ) adds a layer to the image, resulting in an image checksum different than the base image and hence constitutes a new image.

Answer (score 1):

Because we want to have enviroment for **reproducible** build. We don't want to depend on version of language, existence of compiler, version of libraires and so on.

Comment: Reproducible builds can be done just fine without docker

Answer (score 1):

Building inside a Dockerfile allows you to have all the tools and environment you need inside independently of your platform and ready to use. In a development perspective is easier to have all you need inside the container.

But you have to think about the objective of building inside a Dockerfile, if you have a very complex build process with a lot of dependencies you have to be worried about having all the tools inside and it reflects on the final size of your resulting image. Because this is not the same building to generate an artifact than building to produce the final container.

Thinking about this two aspects you have to learn to use the multistage build process in Docker [here](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/). The main idea is closer to your question because you can have a as many stages as you need depending on your build process and use different `FROM` images to ensure you have the correct requirements and dependences on each stage, to finally generate the image with the minimum dependencies and smaller size.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add to the answers above:

Doing builds in or out of docker is a choice that depends on your goal. In my case I am more interested in docker containers for kubernetes, and in addition we have mature builds already.

This link shows how you take prebuilt tasks and add them to an image. This strategy together with adding libs, env etc leverages docker well and shows that indeed docker is flexible. https://medium.com/@chemidy/create-the-smallest-and-secured-golang-docker-image-based-on-scratch-4752223b7324

Comment: Adding further to my question and answer: bazel does reliable builds and supports making docker images without having docker (and thus possibly special logins) running.